# bat file to delete containing folder when double clicked?

Tags: windows, batch-file, uninstallation, rmdir

What I would like to do in my batch file is delete ALL the contents of the containing directory AND the directory itself.  Currently I am using the following command:

```
rmdir ..\dir /S /Q & exit
```

This works in that it deletes ALL of the contents in dir including the batch file but it fails to delete the directory, dir.  Is there a way to do this while deleting the dir also?  Essentially what I would like to do is create a batch script that would reside inside a ZIP file and deletes everything that gets created from unzipping the file.  The above command still leaves behind an empty directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following?

```
cd ..
rmdir .\dir /S /Q & exit
```

You can't delete a directory which is occupied by a running process.

Comment: Thanks! That did not even occur to me to just go up one level before doing it.